# Browsing "outside" code in IntelliJ

Tags: java, browser, intellij-idea

I have lots of Java code written by other people and not residing in an IntelliJ project.

Is there any plugin that will allow me to point to a directory (e.g. org) and have it traverse the subdirectories, locating each Java source file. I would then like to be able to open the source files *readonly* to browse them (with identifier searching, etc.)

Something like this exists in TextMate, but I can't easily find symbol definitions.

Thanks.

**EDIT**: If there is another tool (preferably open source), that does this and runs in OS X, I'd like to hear about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to your Project Structure and set up libraries, you can point those libraries to their source code, which can be anywhere on the file system. I'm not sure about making them read only, other then doing that on the OS level.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. The "readonly" part was only to keep my fat, grubby fingers from accidentally making changes :-).

Comment: @Ralph, if the code has been released as a jar and the source also in a jar, it will be readonly.